# Convert BBCode-generated HTML back to BBCode

Tags: php, html, regex, parsing, bbcode

I have this function to parse bbcode -> html:

```
$this->text = preg_replace(array(
    '/\[b\](.*?)\[\/b\]/ms', 
    '/\[i\](.*?)\[\/i\]/ms',
    '/\[u\](.*?)\[\/u\]/ms',
    '/\[img\](.*?)\[\/img\]/ms',
    '/\[email\](.*?)\[\/email\]/ms',
    '/\[url\="?(.*?)"?\](.*?)\[\/url\]/ms',
    '/\[size\="?(.*?)"?\](.*?)\[\/size\]/ms',
    '/\[youtube\](.*?)\[\/youtube\]/ms',
    '/\[color\="?(.*?)"?\](.*?)\[\/color\]/ms',    
    '/\[quote](.*?)\[\/quote\]/ms',
    '/\[list\=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/list\]/ms',
    '/\[list\](.*?)\[\/list\]/ms',
    '/\[\*\]\s?(.*?)\n/ms'
   ),array(
    '<strong>\1</strong>',
    '<em>\1</em>',
    '<u>\1</u>',
    '<img src="\1" alt="\1" />',
    '<a href="mailto:\1">\1</a>',
    '<a href="\1">\2</a>',
    '<span style="font-size:\1%">\2</span>',
    '<object width="450" height="350"><param name="movie" value="\1"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="\1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="450" height="350"></embed></object>',
    '<span style="color:\1">\2</span>',
    '<blockquote>\1</blockquote>',
    '<ol start="\1">\2</ol>',
    '<ul>\1</ul>',
    '<li>\1</li>'
   ),
   $original
);
```

Problem is, how to unparse this, like html -> bbcode?

Comment: The `m` pattern modifier has no affect if there are no start or end of string modifiers (`^`, `$`). Some pattern consolidation can be enjoyed using backreferences in similar patterns.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't.

Instead, store both the *original* unparsed text and the *processed* parsed text.  Yes, this doubles the storage requirement, but it also makes it blindingly easy to:

1. Allow user edits of the original without parsing the BBCode back out
2. Allow quotes of other user posts, again without parsing
3. Change the HTML each BBCode generates (just re-parse every post)
4. Switch BBCode engines down the line (again, just re-parse every post)

Comment: +1 If indeed the data has been available in BBCode format this would be far preferable.

Comment: Thanks, i think that's a better approach than what i originally thought.

Answer (score 5):

It's pretty safe to say it's nigh impossible to build a *reliable*  way to convert html to bbcode with just a slew of regexes. Use a parser (DOMDocument for instance), remove invalid elements & attributes with xpath's & inspection and then recursively walk it creating a bbcode string on the way (or just ignore invalid tags / attributes on the way).

Comment: Erm, care to clarify? "Tony the pony will not come." is a bit to cryptic for my liking ;)

Comment: Since BBCODE has a recursive structure just like HTML, this applies: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/193892

Comment: And at the bottom of the answer you will find tony the pony aka cthulhu.

Answer (score 3):

If you know exactly that the HTML code you want to de-bbcode was en-bbcoded using your method, than do the following:

Switch the two array you pass to `preg_replace`.

In the array with the HTML code, do the following for every element: Prepend `#` to the string. Append `#s`. Replace `\1` (and `\2` aso) with `(.*?)`.

For the array with the bbcodes do thefollowing with every element: Remove `/` at the beginning and `/ms` at end. Replace `\s` with . Remove all `\`. Remove all `?`. Replace the first `(.*)` in the string with `$1` and the second with `$2`.

This should do. If any problems: Ask ;)